# Change the color of trading-view chart bars

Tags: finance, tradingview-api, pine-script

I am using trading-view chart in my application. I want to change the color of bars mentioned in the picture below.

[image]

I could change the color of above bars using

```
"mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor": "#6A833A",
"mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.downColor": "#8A3A3B"
```

The same way I want to change the color of the bars(mentioned bars in the above picture). I have searched so many places but with no success. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Please provide more information. What are those "bars" are they `candle` bars or `histograms` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the candle bars, you can change their [properties](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Bar_states._Built-in_variables_%E2%80%98barstate%E2%80%99) and coloring scheme like this:

```
study("Example barstate", overlay = true)
last = barstate.islast
barcolor(color = last ? black: na)  // This will make last candle black
```

To get all previous candles black, you'd use:

```
last = barstate.ishistory
```